# Change body class when it has aurelia-app attached

Tags: aurelia

Shortly I have two shells/roots: one for login page and one for the rest of the application and switch between them given the user is logged in or not.

My aurelia-app is attached to body element but I have distinct body classes for login and the rest of the application.

What is the best way to also switch body classes depending on the active shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way is changing the body class in the main.js file. For instance:

```
let rootComponent = '';
aurelia.start().then(a => {
  if (!app.isLoggedIn()) { //<--- example of func to check if the user is logged in
    document.body.className = "example-class-1";
    rootComponent = 'login/login'; 
  } else {
    document.body.className = "example-class-2";
    rootComponent = 'app/app';
  }
  a.setRoot(rootComponent, document.body);
});
```

Hope this helps!